# Where did the use of the conjunction "So,..." at the beginning of a reply come from?

Tags: british-english, conjunctions

I am hearing more incidences of people being asked a direct question responding with a reply beginning with

> So, ...

For example,

> Questioner: "What do you think we should buy Janice for her birthday present?"
>
> Respondent: "So, I thought that a voucher towards the cost of a meal for 2 at an expensive restaurant would be good, but with the Covid lockdown, I don't know when she would get any use out of it."

When, where and how did this enter into the English Language?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was not provided with those threads when carrying out a search, hence my question.  As you can see, I accepted the 2 suggestions made a few seconds before you posted this comment and closed my question as a duplicate

Comment: "So" is not a conjunction, but an adverb functioning as a connective adjunct.

Comment: @BillJ you are correct in your assertion that "so" can be an adverb, but it can also be a conjunction (among others). See [this Merriam Webster entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so) or [this Cambridge Dictionary entry](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so) or [this Oxford Learner's Dictionary entry](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/so_3)

Comment: @ChrisRogers I wouldn't go along with you there. "So" is either an adverb, e.g. in the OP's example, or a preposition with a content clause complement, typically occurring in result or purpose adjuncts. It does not occur as a conjunction, despite what dictionaries tell us. They are fine for meanings, but hopeless for anything else!